# How to add dynamic properties in custom control

Tags: c#, properties, custom-controls

I have created a `windows custom control` in `C#` which inherits from `TextBox`.

In my control i've two properties  namely `Continent` and `Country`

So, i need to give provision to select continent and country for the user.

i. e, if the user need to select the continent, i'll list out all the seven continents, at that time the country list will be empty,

Once the user selected the continent, then the `country` list should be filled with the countries in the selected continent.

i know i can use `enum` for this

i.e

```
public enum Continents {Asia , Africa, Antartica, Australia, Europe, NorthAmerica, SouthAmerica }
```

and the property

```
public Continents  Continent { get; set; }
```

if i set like this, then the `continent property` will provides a `dropdown list` ( list of continents from the above `enum` ) to the user, from which( from the property window) the user can select.

Now my problem is that, once the `continen`t got selected , then the user should able to select the `country` from the property window.

Please help me to do this

Comment: @gideon : i can not set a `Country` property since it is dynamic. and more over i have no idea about the type of `country`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you want two drop-down lists:

- One for continent
- One for country

You have properties on your custom control that match.

The first thing you need to do is get your list of continents and countries (perhaps as a `Dictionary` with Country as the key [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)).

Databind the first control to the unique values in the Dictionary, something like `var continents = myDictionary.Values.Distinct();` [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx)

Then you can hook into the SelectedIndexChanged [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) to databind the second drop down to the countries matching the selected continent (you can get the selected item from the first textbox and then lookup by key from the dictionary).

I hope that helps - good luck!